# What is the different between this 2 statement

Tags: apex, soql

i am new to APEX and wondering what is the different between the 2 statements below and which should be the best practice?

1)

```
List<Contact> c1 = [select id, firstname from Contact];

for(Contact c2: c1){
    c2.firstname = 'Test';
}
update c1;
```

2)

```
List<Contact> c1 = [select id, firstname from Contact];
List<Contact> c3 = new List<Contact>();

for(Contact c2: c1){
    c2.firstname = 'Test';
    c3.add(c2);
}
update c3;
```

both update the contact name to 'Test'. i just confuse why the first one works as i'm assigning new value (Test) into c2 but not c1? I though c1 would still have the old value? what would be use case for it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

In the end, both of your approaches are functionally identical. Explaining why this is the case requires some background information...

### The background (how are variables passed?)

The key concept here is distinguishing *pass-by-value* and *pass-by-reference*.

In a nutshell, when you have something that is passed by-value, you're given an *independent copy*. We get an entire copy of the variable at a new location in memory.

```
Integer myInt = 1;

public class MyClass{
    public void changeVariable(Integer input){
        System.debug('input before modification: ' + input);
        input += 1;
        System.debug('input after modification: ' + input);
    }
}

System.debug('myInt before: ' + myInt);
MyClass myInstance = new MyClass();
myInstance.changeVariable(myInt);
System.debug('myInt after: ' + myInt);

// running this code as anoymous apex will produce the following output in your log
// myInt before: 1
// input before modification: 1
// input after modification: 2
// myInt after: 1
```

The Integer is passed by-value, so copies that we make are independent. When we change the value of the integer in the `changeVariable()` method, we only changed the copy of the integer *local to the `changeVariable()` method's scope*.

In contrast, when something is passed by-reference, we don't get an independent copy. Instead *we are (effectively) given a reference to the memory location of the original copy*. Let's modify the previous example a bit...

```
Account myAccount = new Account(Name = 'myAccount');

public class MyClass{
    public void changeVariable(Account input){
        System.debug('input before modification: ' + input);
        input.Name += ' modified!';
        System.debug('input after modification: ' + input);
    }
}

System.debug('myAccount.Name before: ' + myAccount.Name);
MyClass myInstance = new MyClass();
myInstance.changeVariable(myAccount);
System.debug('myAccount.Name after: ' + myAccount.Name);

// running this code as anoymous apex will produce the following output in your log
// myAccount.Name before: myAccount
// input before modification: myAccount
// input after modification: myAccount modified!
// myAccount.Name after: myAccount modified!
```

Because we aren't working with an independent copy in this situation, any change to the "reference" copy *also changes the original*.

In Apex, we can't control whether something is passed by-value or passed by-reference. The rule of thumb is:

- Primitive types (`Integer`, `String`, `Boolean`, etc...) and collections (list, set, map) of primitive types are passed by-value
- Other types (SObjects like `Account` or `Opportunity`, Apex classes that you create) and collections thereof are passed by-reference

### Why your first code example works (changes the name of the Contact)

Lists of SObjects store *references*.

When you use a for loop to iterate over a list of SObjects, the loop variable (`c2` in your first example) is populated with a *reference* to the memory location that actually contains your `Contact` data.

Making a change to the reference changes the original as well.

### Why your two code examples are (effectively) the same

In your second example, the loop variable `c2` is still a reference to a `Contact` record in some memory location.

When you store `c2` in your other list, `c3`, you are just creating *another reference* (so you have 1 original copy and 2 references, `c2` and another reference stored in `c3`).

The "original" copy of the `Contact` (stored in `c1`) is still modified in your second example.

### Best practice:

Your first example is best practice in this case. It's about as short as can be, doesn't spend time creating things that ultimately don't serve any purpose, and doesn't clutter the namespace.

There could be an argument for using a "SOQL for-loop" (i.e. `for(Contact c :[<your contact query here>]){`). That said, I don't think most people are ever going to encounter a situation where the decision between a SOQL for-loop and directly storing the query results in a collection is going to make any appreciable difference.

Just to be clear, there *is* a difference between those two strategies. It's just not going to be a *meaningful difference* in most situations.

### Bonus: How to make an independent copy of an SObject

If you use the `clone()` method on an SObject, or the `deepClone()` method on a collection of SObjects, then you do get a completely separate, independent copy.

This is only true of SObjects (as far as I know). If you `clone()` an instance of an Apex class, you still get a reference. The `deepClone()` collection method only works on collections of SObjects, and the regular `clone()` method does not make an independent copy.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, both work and give the same output. But there is a difference of how data is stored in them.

In first one you have directly query the data and update them, You have only created single list so it will help you in heap size, view state.

The second option you are just creating a duplicate list, this option is better if you need to update only selected record based on some condition. So you can filter the records and add them another list to use later or simple update.

But in your use case, both will give the same output.

<strike>On a lighter note, your code will not work and you will get `Field is not writeable: Contact.Name` exception. You can try with Account instead.</strike>
 As OP has updated the field, so this is outdated.

Comment: he is not updating name he is updating firstname so how it can give the error field is not writable?

Comment: @cloudZigZag if you check the edit history, he changed the field reference, before it  was name.

Answer (score 0):

1. In the first code snippet you have made changes to the contact list
   you have queried using c2 as reference variable.
2. In the second one, you have did the same thing as in first snippet
   and you have just made a replica of the queried list. Now both the
   list contains same data which means both the list points to the same
   object reference.

Answer (score 0):

For the (1) code snippet update all contacts. But does not alter any field values.

(2) code snippet is the one which update all contact name to "Test". But this code will not compile. Because you cannot update Contact's `Name` field, its not writeable. You will get a compilation error says:

> Field is not writeable: Contact.Name

`Name` field is concatenation of `FirstName`, `MiddleName`, `LastName`, and `Suffix`. You need to fill all the required fields among these to populate Name.

From [Contact documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_contact.htm):

> **Type** string
>   **Properties** Filter, Group, Sort
>   **Description** Concatenation
>   of FirstName, MiddleName, LastName, and Suffix up to 121 characters.